# Run expensive / UI coroutines in parallel

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Given the following code example:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun main() {
    val inputChannel = Channel<Unit>()
    val outputChannel = Channel<String>()
    val engine = Engine(outputChannel)
    val calculator = Logger()

    runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
        launch {
            engine.connect(inputChannel)
        }

        launch {
            calculator.connect(outputChannel)
        }

        inputChannel.send(Unit)
        inputChannel.send(Unit)
    }
}

class Engine(private val logger: SendChannel<String>) {

    private val pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool().asCoroutineDispatcher()

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    suspend fun connect(input: ReceiveChannel<Unit>) {
        input.consumeEach {
            println("${Instant.now()} [${Thread.currentThread().name}] Engine - Received input")
            // What to do here so `calc()` runs in parallel, not blocking the channel?
            calc()
        }
    }

    suspend fun calc() {
        logger.send("Starting processing")
        for (i in 1..100) {
            delay(100)
            print(".")
        }
        println()
        logger.send("Finished processing")
    }
}

class Logger {

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    suspend fun connect(channel: ReceiveChannel<String>) {
        channel.consumeEach {
            println("${Instant.now()} [${Thread.currentThread().name}] Logger - $it")
        }
    }
}
```

The log output shows

```
2021-11-14T11:50:21.021357700Z [main] Engine - Received input
2021-11-14T11:50:21.025358900Z [main] Logger - Starting processing
....................................................................................................
2021-11-14T11:50:31.829252900Z [main] Engine - Received input
2021-11-14T11:50:31.829252900Z [main] Logger - Finished processing
2021-11-14T11:50:31.829252900Z [main] Logger - Starting processing
....................................................................................................
2021-11-14T11:50:42.686953100Z [main] Logger - Finished processing
```

that all things are happening on the same thread. However, I would like `Engine` to be able to calculate inputs in parallel (this is just a MWE in place of a much larger and more complex application that requires things to run in parallel).

What to I need to change in this code so that messages to `inputChannel` will spawn multiple ... "scopes" (?) in which calculations can happen **and** that can send messages to `outputChannel` during processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `runBlocking()` like this you start a single-threaded dispatcher and all child coroutines are dispatched on this single thread. If you need to perform mostly CPU-intensive calculations then use [Dispatchers.Default](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html) instead:

```kotlin
runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) { ... }
```

Then, if you need to perform blocking IO inside this code, enclose it in:

```kotlin
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }
```

Comment: I updated the question to more accurately reflect the real code. Also I tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to change it (I wrapped `calc()` in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` but the log output remains the same. The input messages are calculated consecutively and not in parallel

Comment: Ahh, ok, I missed the fact the you use channel with a single consumer. This is actually a common pattern if we need to process some tasks sequentially ;-) Depending on your needs you can put `launch()` inside `consumeEach()` to not wait for the processing (and put `consumeEach()` inside `coroutineScope()` as well). Alternatively, you can remove the channel entirely and add a function to `Engine` like: `fun suspend performSomething(data: Data)`, then `launch()` it from the caller side instead of sending messages.

Comment: I ended up switching to `MutableSharedFlow` as it better represents my use case. Thanks for your input anyway :-)